# For a Gaussian process, how does $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}, {\sigma_n}^2\mathbf{I})$ relate to the Normal PDF?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am told during the Gaussian Process class that the following notations are equivalent as convention:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{f} &\sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}, {\sigma_n}^2\mathbf{I}) \\ 
p(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{f}) &= \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{f}, {\sigma_n}^2\mathbf{I})
\end{align*}

How does it relate to the typical definition of pdf of a Gaussian distribution:

> **Normal Probability Density Function**
>   $$F(x) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

Comment: @max I have flagged my question to move to stats exchange site since it is more relevant and has a gaussian process tag. Could you help to move it?

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. Flagging might have been the right thing to do. I'm not sure. I think it would be ok for you to copy-and-paste this question to a new question on Cross Validated SE and then delete this one. But I'm not sure. I do not think it should be a big problem though.

Comment: Also, this kind of question is relevant here too. If your question is not getting enough attention, then consider looking at this post: [How to grab users' attention on an old question?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3478/how-to-grab-users-attention-on-an-old-question)

Comment: @Max thanks for the info!